# kubectl exec -it - kill the process

Tags: kubernetes

I have a running container with a running app.

Now

```
 kubectl exec -it <deployment> bash
```

This container exposes port 80, and I want to debug some code starting a new process on port 80 - how?

if I do `kill <PID>`, then the exec shell terminates with:

command terminated with exit code 137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your container it will run until the main process (defined on `command` field of the container spec) exit. When you run the `kill` command the container is marked as complete.

To debug like this you should run your application without starting the main application. You can run `kubectl run myappdebug -it --image=YOUR_IMAGE bash` than you'll be able to debug it.

After you finish it, remember to remove the deployment with your debug: `kubectl del deployment/myappdebug`